# Yield a fetched file line by line in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a huge JSONL file I need to parse.

It's really huge, so I can't download it.

I wanted to do something like this:

```js
import { request } from "https";

request(operation.url, async (res) => {
  try {
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: res,
      crlfDelay: Infinity,
    });
    for await (const line of rl) {
      yield JSON.parse(line);
    }
  } catch (error) { }
}).end();
```

But the callback is not a generator, so this ain't working.

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: This just isn't possible. Although you can read http endpoints part by part using streams; JSON cannot be parsed without having all of it.

Comment: Where do you want to `yield` to? What do you want to do with the lines?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can split a string in lines, e.g.

```
const arr = data.toString().replace(/\r\n/g,'\n').split('\n')
```

for windows.. or easier for Linux,

```
const arr = data.toString().split('\n')
```

and then, you can handle the chunk..

```
for (let s of arr) 
{ 
  handleMyString(s); 
}
```